# How to forward Hive UDTF output with the last input row

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, udf

Hive UDTF process each row singly and forward output for each row.
I need to do some manipulations with all function output.
Is there way to forward all function output one time after all rows was processed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such way exists.

1. To make some changes with ***all*** output of UDF, you have firstly to
   store it. So, create the field in UDF class to collect the output in
   it: `private List<SomeClass> output = new ArrayList<>();`
2. Then in your `process()` method you should use `output.add()` instead
   of `forward()`. So in `process()` the `output` will be filled.
3. And finally you have the `close()` method. It is used for cleaning
   up after all processing and usually it's not necessary to code
   something in it. However in your case, `close()` is a good
   possibility to process `output` collection and forward it.

The approximate code of `close()` is here:

```
@Override
public void close() throws HiveException {
    for(String record: output){
        forwardObjArray[0] = record.substring(3);
        forward(forwardObjArray);
    }
}
```

`forwardObjArray` is another private field of UDF. It is used to optimize resource usage (to avoid creation array with 1 element before each `forward()` call).

But this way applicable only if you run UDTF on small dataset. Otherwise `output` collection will be extremely large.

If you're going to run UDTF on large input data, I recommend to use two UDTFs. As current Hive version dosn't allow to use nested UDTFs, you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT func2(processed)
FROM (
    SELECT func1(fiels) AS processed
    FROM table
) AS interm_table;
```

In `func2()` you'll implement the logic used to manipulate the output of `func1()`.